# PHP getdate() conversion to Java Date

Tags: java, php, android, date

I had this weird problem a little while ago and haven't been able to find a solution yet. In my application, I keep some information about the activity of the user on my server. I also keep the date of the activity using *getdate()* function of PHP. When queried, I send this information back to the phone and try to represent the date in a more human-readable format.

For example,

```
//This is the part that runs on the server
$timeOfAct = getdate();
//$timeOfAct = 1339637005. I guess this is the date in milliseconds
//INSERT $timeOfAct to database
```

I send this information back to the application using JSON.

```
//st="1339637005"
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date resultdate = new Date(Long.parseLong(st));
st=ft.format(resultdate);
```

st always becomes 01/16/1970.

As far as I understand, date 0 for JAVA is not equal to 0 for PHP.

So, do you have any suggestions for me to achieve a successful conversion?

UPDATE: I forgot to mention that I was using the 0th element of the array returned by *getdate()* which is equal to what is returned by *time()* function

//E.g. INSERT $timeOfAct[0]

Comment: [`getdate`](http://php.net/getdate) returns an array. Are you sure you're using it appropriately?

Comment: No I am not sure, actually. I am going to check it. Thanks.

Comment: Surprisingly, I was using it appropriately. I was using the 0th element of the array ($timeOfAct[0])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getdate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php) returns an associative array of information related to the timestamp, not what you guessed.

If you want timestamp, just use [`time()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php).

Comment: Shouldn't be `time() * 1000`?

Comment: I was using the 0th element in the array which indeed is equal to time(). I didn't know that at first but it seems so.

Comment: Sorry that was my bad. I have always assumed that getdate returns the time in ms. Whatever, thanks for your time